# Can someone clarify this unification algorithm?

Tags: logic, artificial-intelligence, first-order-logic, unification

I've been having trouble understanding a unification algorithm for first order logic, as I don't know what a compound expression is. I googled it, but found nothing relevant. I also don't know what a list means in this context. A list of what?

Edit: I think I've cleared up with compound expressions are and what lists contain in this context, from Yuval Filmus's answer. However, now I have other problems:

- In Unify-Var, it uses the variable(?) val, even though val was never declared. Could {var/val} E theta (with E meaning is a subset of) instead be a function that returns whether var is already in theta, regardless of what value it's mapped to?
- The algorithm seems to break when unifying compound expressions. To unify them, it breaks compound expressions into two lists: one for function symbols and one for arguments and then calls Unify on both individually. When trying to unify the list of function symbols, it breaks the list into individual function symbols and then calls Unify on each individual function symbol. But Unify has no case to deal with function symbols, so it just returns failure, even if the two function symbols to be unified are identical!

Thanks.

Pseudocode from Artificial Intelligence A Modern Approach (3rd Edition): Figure 9.1, page
328:

```
function UNIFY(x, y, theta) returns a substitution to make x and y identical
  inputs: x, a variable, constant, list, or compound expression
          y, a variable, constant, list, or compound expression
          theta, the substitution built up so far (optional, defaults to empty)

  if theta = failure then return failure
  else if x = y the return theta
  else if VARIABLE?(x) then return UNIFY-VAR(x, y, theta)
  else if VARIABLE?(y) then return UNIFY-VAR(y, x, theta)
  else if COMPOUND?(x) and COMPOUND?(y) then
      return UNIFY(x.ARGS, y.ARGS, UNIFY(x.OP, y.OP, theta))
  else if LIST?(x) and LIST?(y) then
      return UNIFY(x.REST, y.REST, UNIFY(x.FIRST, y.FIRST, theta))
  else return failure

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function UNIFY-VAR(var, x, theta) returns a substitution

  if {var/val} E theta then return UNIFY(val, x, theta)
  else if {x/val} E theta then return UNIFY(var, val, theta)
  else if OCCUR-CHECK?(var, x) then return failure
  else return add {var/x} to theta
```

Figure 9.1 The unification algorithm. The algorithm works by comparing the
structures of the inputs, elements by element. The substitution theta that is
the argument to UNIFY is built up along the way and is used to make sure that
later comparisons are consistent with bindings that were established earlier.
In a compound expression, such as F(A, B), the OP field picks out the
function symbol F and the ARGS field picks out the argument list (A, B).

Comment: I answered your further questions in comments to my answer. But I really feel that this information appears in the textbook somewhere, perhaps in earlier chapters. Finally, it would probably be better if you could talk to peers, TAs or the helpdesk, or consult a different textbook, since explaining every line of code is probably out of scope here.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus This is my second time reading the textbook and I already read ahead again after I got stuck. What's a TA? I couldn't find a help desk for Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach nor do I have any peers, as I'm not taking a course that uses the book.

Comment: TA=Teaching Assistant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, unification algorithms are tricky. Studying other textbooks will help.

Second, things will probably get clearer if you look at actual code implementations. Have a look at [the online code repository for your textbook](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/code.html). The code in Lisp, for example, [is here](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/lisp/logic/algorithms/unify.lisp).

A helpful note to remember when looking at first-order unification algorithms is that function symbols and predicates must match exactly in order to be correct.

On to your questions.

- (Where is val declared?) This is a notational trick in the pseudocode that creates more confusion than good. It hearkens back to the old days of [Lisp association lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_list). Maybe giving an example of theta would help: ((x 1) (y 2) (z 3)). This means x is bound to 1, y is bound to 2, and z is bound to 3. So var/val refers to a pair in theta like (x 1). So the first clause in UNIFY-VAR means, "if the pair (var val) is a member of theta, then return the result of doing UNIFY on whatever val is in that pair, with x and theta".
- (How do function symbols get unified?) Remember that function symbols must match exactly as I pointed out above. So actually the clause `else if x = y then return theta` covers this. This is via a recursive call through an outer COMPOUND case.

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit more in how the function symbols get unified?

Comment: @novalain: They have to match exactly. If you need more details, let me know.

Answer (score 4):

## This algorithm presentation is indeed pedagogically unclear.

I will not repeat here the previous contributions. However, I believe
some points need clarification. Sorry if some of it is a bit subtle:
this program is far from being pedagogically written. I am thinking in particular of the presentation of the function  `UNIFY-VAR` which is analyzed below.

First one should note that we have two languages here, both with variables and constants, which may lead to much confusion if one is not very careful in the terminology. Hence my somewhat verbose presentation:

- the *object language* defining the expressions being unified
- the *programming language* which is a *meta-language* for the
  object language, and in which the unification algorithm is expressed.

### Regarding the object language

Apparently the OP could not find in his book the definition of the
object language, and hence did not know what a *compound expression*
may be. I do not have the book to check and can only guess. But it is
quite abnormal to give a unification algorithm without a reference to
a precise definition and terminology of the object language in which
unification is defined.  There are many such object languages, and
unification may depend on them and their properties.

In this case my guess is that *compound expression* stands for an expression
composed of an operator and its operands. So if the metavariable `x`
has a compound expression as value, then `x.OP` is the operator while
`x.ARGS` is the list of its arguments.

But then we do not see anywhere what unifies operators. The
explanation is probably, as indicated by Yval Filmus in a comment,
that operators are treated as constant. Actually, as far as I know,
the habit is more to say that constants are operators without
arguments. But indeed, both can be treated in the same way. But again,
being explicit about it would not hurt the pedagogy, since few
students are used to treat the `+` symbols as a constant, for example.

To conclude, the object language is just a language composed of
expressions, where an expression is either an *atomic expression*,
i.e. a constant or a variable, or a *compound expression* that applies
an operator (given by its name) to a list of arguments which are
expressions.

The name *compound expression* is in this context opposed to *atomic
expression*. The former has to be decomposed for unification, while
the latter cannot be decomposed.

### About the function `function UNIFY-VAR(var, x, theta) returns a substitution`

First note that the value of the argument `var` is always an object
variable, while the value of `x` is always an object expression (which
could be reduced to a variable).

The use of `if {var/val} E theta` here is a strange thing to do when
describing a unification algorithm for the object language, since it is implicitly using
unification at the programming language level, and in a strange way.

In the pair `{var/val}`

- `var` stands for the value of the meta-variable (i.e. programming
  language variable) `var`, i.e. for the object variable passed as
  argument. This object variable is a constant from the meta point of view
  of the programming language.
- `val` stands for itself, as a meta-variable: it was not assigned any
  value, and thus can hardly be expected to stand for its value.
- the pair `{var/val}` is just a meta compound expression, a construction,
  involving the pair operator, a constant (the value of `var`), and the
  variable `val`, at the meta level of the programming language.

The use of `if {var/val} E theta then do X` is actually intended to say, but at
the meta level:

> if the meta expression `{[var]/val}` unifies with an element of theta
>     , then do X.

where I insist again with the notation `[var]` that the variable `var` is replaced by its value,
while `val` is not (and acts somewhat as what Prolog calls a logical variable).

Furthermore it does have a side effect: when the unification succeeds,
then the variable `val` takes the value of the second component of the
substitution pair with whch it actually unified. And this value is to
be used in whatever is to be done, in this case `return UNIFY(val, x, theta)`.

So this is not at all trivial. Furthermore, it is pedagogically unwise (to understate it),
when teaching beginners, since it is using unification at the
programming level to define unification at the object level.

Note that is no unification succeeds in the above test, the variable
`val` remains undefined. Then the next test `if {x/val} E theta then ...` is again a unification, slightly more complex, since the meta
variable `x` is not necessarily a variable, though it will unify only
if it is one.

In the last line the construction `{var/x}` is used again, but in this
case, both variables stand for their values.

So again, reading this piece of programming is a bit subtle, at least
for a beginner. It do not mean it is nad programming, only that it
mixes too many concepts and levels from a pedagogical point of view.

### Occur-check

Finally, I do hope you understand what the call to `OCCUR-CHECK?` is
supposed to do, because it is an essential part of the algorithm.

Essentially it is suppose to verify that when you try to unify a
variable with an expression that the variable does not appear in the
expression (allowing it would correspond to looping structures that
are not usually allowed in the language).

Note that in the call to `[OCCUR-CHECK][1]?(var, x)` in your program, the
meta-variable `var`
is supposed to have as value an object variable, and the meta-variable
`x` is supposed to have as value an object expression, and the
function will check that the object variable does not occur in the
object expression.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. I think I understand it now. Just one issue: you said that the occurs check is essential, but according to the textbook, Prolog omits the occurs check and omitting it almost never causes problems.

Comment: Well, I am not a Prolog specialist. Prolog has a very pragmatic view
of some logical problems (occur-check is not the only one), and
**experienced Prolog programmers** know how to deal with them. Not doing
the occur-check may have sense, but you are then no longer in a world
of expressions that can be represented by trees, but in a more complex
universe with looping structures. The unification of a variable with
and expression that contains it amounts to saying that the expression
is a subexpression of itself where the variable occurs. This can make
sense, but has to be properly formalized.

Comment: @Kyth'Py1k It may well be that for a lot of simpler programs, and some care, you do not run too much in this problem. But if you run nto it, you have a buggy program. However, saying more about it requires more experience than I have with Prolog. My remark was only that within the pure logic framework you seem to be considering, you should be careful with occur-check. Also, if future work leads you to skip it, you should make sure you understand well the implications. Unification is only a form of equation solving in specific domains. You are now using one. You may have to consider variations.

Comment: @Kyth'Py1k You can do a bit of research on occur-check on the web. Here is one document I found which  holds a discussion by expert people (several have very high reputation as scientists): http://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/projects/ALP/newsletter/archive_93_96/net/impl/occur.html . You may also want to look at rational trees unification. But this is probably beyong the curriculum of your class.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the code, a *compound expression* is a function call such as `UNIFY(x, y, theta)`. It has an `OP` part, in this case `UNIFY`, and an `ARGS` part, in this case the list `x, y, theta`. Compound expressions can be nested or appear within other structures (such as lists). They can also appear in infix notation: `1 + 2`.

A *list* is a primitive data structure, which decomposes into its head (first element) `FIRST` and the rest of the list `REST`. According to the code, the empty list isn't considered a list but rather a constant. If we want, we can represent lists using angular brackets: `[1,2,3]`. We have `[1,2,3].FIRST = 1`, `[1,2,3].REST = [2,3]`, `[2,3].FIRST = 2`, `[2,3].REST = [3]`, `[3].FIRST = 3`, `[3].REST = []`, where `[]` is apparently a constant. Lists can be nested: `[1,[2,3],4]`. They can also appear inside compound expressions, or appear as arguments to compound expressions.

The members of a list have arbitrary type, at least as far as this code is concerned. They could contain constants, variables, other lists, and compound expressions.

Comment: Ok, but the algorithm still seems to make no sense. In Unify-Var, it uses the variable(?) val, even though val was never declared. Could {var/val} E theta (with E meaning is a subset of) instead be a function that returns whether  var is already in theta, regardless of what value it's mapped to?

Comment: @Kyth'Py1k I have no idea. You have access to the textbook. I'm sure they explain the algorithm and their notation, hopefully through examples. If you have complaints maybe you should aim them at the authors.

Comment: No, unless I missed it, the book never mentions what val means.

Comment: Regardless, I still have other issues. The algorithm seems to break when unifying compound expressions. To unify them, it breaks compound expressions into two lists: one for function symbols and one for arguments and then calls Unify on both individually. When trying to unify the list of function symbols, it breaks the list into individual function symbols and then calls Unify on each individual function symbol. But Unify has no case to deal with function symbols, so it just returns failure, even if the two function symbols to be unified are identical!

Comment: @ Yuval Filmus What makes you think that a compound expression is a function call? First off, first order logic is a "declarative" language, so it can't be a literal function call. Also, the description of the algorithm gave F(A,B) as an example of a compound expression, but never actually defined it.

Comment: Function symbols are probably treated as constants. Compound expressions appear to be function calls since they have an `ARGS` part.

Comment: Regarding your new question, I think that `E` is not the start symbol but rather the element of symbol $\in$. Also,  `{var/val}` seems to be the ordered pair with parts `var` and `val`. It's not substitution at all.

Comment: I don't recall ever saying that E was a start symbol; I agree that is means the subset symbol. I think that {var/val} is both an ordered pair and a substitution: it's pair that describes what substitution to do. It's the syntax in the book to do substitutions, so I think I'm correct.

Comment: Sorry, I meant subset rather than start. I think it's not subset but rather element of, i.e. $\in$.

Comment: Sorry, I derped. I meant to say set membership. To be clear, E = ∈ = element of.

Comment: @Kyth'Py1k I have not worked on unification for quite a while, but this seems fishy to me. Compounds are apparently operators applied to arguments, which is what we usually call expression. But unification normally proceeds by just checking operators are equal. Trying to unify them means that you are using higher order functions ... which may get you in a much different game, and much harder. The book has to define precisely the syntax of the language to be unified. You must have a precise definition somewhere, including the definition of compound, and what is the OP part of a compound.

Comment: @babou The book seemed to never actually define compound expressions, but I learned what they were from a python implementation of the algorithm. The problem's more or less solved now.

Comment: @Kyth'Py1k You missed my point. I am saying that if the book does not define precisely the syntax of the language it is performing unification on, then it is not worth the paper it is printed on. Unification can be performed on a great variety of structures, and the way it is done depends on these structures. Hence you cannot give a unification algorithm without being clear about the formalism that contains the ëxpressions being unified.